# What's the difference between the Directline API and OAuth2 in Microsoft Bot Framework .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework

I'm thinking of how to implement Authentication in my Bot Project. My Boss wants Directline API from Azure as our go-to but there is no useful documentation provided by the Microsoft team. Another authentication is OAuth2 from Azure. Are these two similar? I know they both provide an Authentication token. But I would like to hear any suggestions from you guys.

I need to embed my Bot to the React Web-App. My plan is to only use the Bot if the user is logged-in within the App. So if it does whenever the user type/send message to the Bot. I need to authenticate that request and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Direct Line service (along with other channel connectors) in the bot framework [utilizes Oauth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#authentication-technologies). The connector service lives (and handles communication) between the chat client and the bot (your code). This is related to authenticating and handling communication between these endpoints. The bot resource (`bot channels registration` or `web app bot`) actually is dependent on an Azure AAD application that gets created along with that resource (uses client secret, etc).

Additionally, *user* authentication can be done, and there are bot framework SDK samples on how to implement that (let me know if you need examples).

Samples:

- [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-samples) is the *main* samples repo with readme.
- [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore) are the .NET
  (core) specific ones.
- [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication) is a sample that shows user
  authentication using OAuth. Remember this is different than client
  (Teams or Slack application for example) or channel authentication.
  This is regarding authenticating a user to the bot through OAuth. The
  readme contains this link already, but make sure you read and follow
  [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv1%2Ccsharp) on how to add authentication.
- [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) is a sample
  using OAuth but also has calls utilizing that, to make calls to
  MSGraph.

Comment: Oh, I would love to see some samples.

Comment: Added sample links in the answer. If you find my answer valid and helpful, please mark it as answered so that others will know.

Comment: Oh, this is good. Thanks man, I finally able to implement it. I greatly appreciated it.